# Require Modernizr with Webpack

Tags: javascript, gruntjs, modernizr, webpack

Trying to use WebPack inside grunt to get all my javascript, css and other stuff build and put in a proper places. Experiencing the following problem while using  `require('modernizer')` inside one of my javascript files that is included in one of modules in my Gruntfile.js. The error is the following:

```
Fatal error: EMFILE, too many open files ../about/node_modules/modernizr/node_modules/file/lib/file.js'
```

When I use `ulimit` to increase the number of files to work with, other errors appear. In my package.json i have the following:

```
"dependencies": {
"jquery": "^2.1.1",
"jquery-ui": "^1.10.5",
"modernizr": "^2.8.3"
```

}

Is there a way to use Modernizer from pack to include it modules without using this directive on page:

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="{portal:createUrl('/_public/about/js/modernizr/modernizr.custom.flexbox.js')}"></script>
```

?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

First of all, just flagging that you should call `require('modernizr')` instead of `require('modernizer')`.

Secondly, to answer your question *“Is there a way to use Modernizer from pack to include it modules without using this directive on page?*

Yes there is. It's the [`script-loader`](https://github.com/webpack/script-loader). It basically allows you to require a library, and execute it as if it were inside a `<script>` tag. You'd use it by calling:

**UPDATE 2017-12-27**

```
require('script-loader');
require('script-loader!modernizr');
```

**PREVIOUSLY**

```
require('script-loader');
require('script!modernizr');
```

Remember to install `script-loader` in advance, by calling `npm install script-loader --save` in your command line.

Comment: Running the `script-loader` I get an `Unexpected token` for the `!` and if I put the `script!modernizr` between `''` it can't find the module 'script!modernizr'. Yes, I did `npm install script-loader`. According to [the package doc](https://www.npmjs.com/package/script-loader), it has to be with `''`. Haven't figured out, which file to actually `script!`.

Comment: @Giszmo I noticed a typo in my previous comment. It should be `'script!modernizr'` not `script!modernizr`. (quotes were missing)

Comment: Looks like it's now:

`require('script-loader'); require('script-loader!modernizr');`